# Apply rewrite rule for all but all the files (recursive) in a subdirectory?

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have an .htaccess file in the root of the website that looks like this

```
RewriteRule ^some-blog-post-title/ http://website/read/flowers/a-new-title-for-this-post/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^some-blog-post-title2/ http://website/read/flowers/a-new-title-for-this-post2/ [R=301,L]

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

## Redirects for all pages except for files in wp-content to website/read
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/wp-content
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://website/read/$1 [L,QSA]

#RewriteRule ^http://website/read [R=301,L]

RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

1. My intent is to redirect people to the new blog post location if
   they propose one of those special blog posts.
2. If that's not the case
       then they should be redirected to http://website.com/read.
3. Nothing from http://website.com/wp-content/* should be redirected.

So far conditions 1 and 3 are being met.  How can I meet condition 2?

Note: I want to redirect to `/read` even for content that exists to prevent any images, CSS, or javascript from working, except those in `/wp-content`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your first rule as:

```
## Redirects for all pages except for files in wp-content to website/read
RewriteRule !^wp-content/ http://website.com/read%{REQUEST_URI} [NC,L,R=302]
```